# Sizing text in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

The canvas seems to default to a width of 300 and a height of 150. What I want it a much smaller canvas with text on it, a tooltip. As such I have three queries about this sample (on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badgerspot/8kdp3/2/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

c.style.height="25px";
//2: This stretches the visible portion of the text. Not what I wanted.
//c.style.width="125px";

ctx.font="130px Georgia";
//3: If I don't want to set the font family this doesn't seem to set the font size.
//ctx.fontSize="130";
ctx.fillText("Hello World!",0,130);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

1. I have reduced the size of the canvas but I need to increase the font size dramatically which seems an odd thing to have to do.  Is this approach correct?
2. I can't get the whole 'Hello World' to display as increasing the size of the canvas stretches the visible portion of the text. How do I show the whole text?
3. How can I set the font size without setting the font family?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
c.width = 200;  // just for example. Defined in pixels using integer values
c.height = 25;
```

CSS only affects the *element* but not the bitmap used for the context. Think of canvas as an edit-able image. An image would simply be stretched with CSS while the actual width and height would be the same as the original.

You can't set the font size without specifying font family.

You can extract current font and alter that:

```
var cFont = ctx.font,
    parts = cFont.split(' ');

if (parts.length === 2) {
    ctx.font = newSize + 'px ' + parts[1];
}
else if (parts.length === 3) {
    ctx.font = parts[0] + ' ' + newSize + 'px ' + parts[2]; //bold/italic/.. used
}
```